# Is there any way to get FullCalendar to trigger a function when an Event is due or in progress?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Is there any way to get FullCalendar to trigger a function when an Event is due or in progress? For example, I would like to pop up a notification that says an Event listed in FullCalendar is about to start.

Comment: fullCalendar has no concept of reminders (which is essentially what you're talking about, I think, if we were to compare this to similar functionality in Outlook or Google Calendar). You'd need some separate code for this, which would run on an interval and, using a list of all events currently displayed in the calendar (which fullCalendar can supply through its methods), check if any of the events are, say, starting in 5 minutes, or are currently in progress. So there's no direct way to automate it within fullCalendar, all you can do is grab the event data and use it in your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the `extendedProps` to assign special properties:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  events: [
    {
      title: 'BCH237',
      start: '2019-08-12T10:30:00',
      end: '2019-08-12T11:30:00',
      extendedProps: {
        'isAboutToStart': true //'2019-08-12T11:30:00' - Date.Now() > 
        'isDue': false // Date.Now() > '2019-08-12T11:30:00'
      },
      description: 'Lecture'
    }
    // more events ...
  ],
  eventDidMount: function(info) {
    console.log(info.event.extendedProps);
    // {description: "Lecture", isAboutToStart: "True", isDue: "False"}
  }    
});
```

And set this value according to the `start` or `end` property.

From Docs:

> A plain object holding miscellaneous other properties specified during
> parsing. Receives properties in the explicitly given extendedProps
> hash as well as other non-standard properties.

Comment: This would only work when events are loaded. It wouldn't do anything if the event starts while the calendar is simply being displayed on screen.

Comment: Correct, but you can always trigger an update every few minutes automatically

Comment: I used this technique to solve the issue (although I used eventDataTransform since I use V4) and did a perodic calendar refresh. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help